# Node Server missing css

Tags: css, node.js, email, backend

I have a small node backend application used to: simple database operations, calling external services, and building emails. To build those templates I'm using Handlebars. Every email includes its own HTML and CSS files. In the development process, those files are available in runtime. But in the production build not. I noticed that the build command only touches *.js files. All other files are not built, and not visible in the build folder in the final step. In fact on production, only emails don't work. How to force node build command to compile also CSS, HTML files.

package.json build command:

```
"build": "babel src -d build",
```

build output:

```
src/constants/errorMessages.js -> build/constants/errorMessages.js
src/constants/index.js -> build/constants/index.js 
src/index.js -> build/index.js
src/lib/email.js -> build/lib/email.js
src/lib/emailBuilder/index.js -> build/lib/emailBuilder/index.js
src/lib/index.js -> build/lib/index.js
src/lib/mongo.js -> build/lib/mongo.js
src/lib/responses.js -> build/lib/responses.js
src/resolvers/index.js -> build/resolvers/index.js
src/resolvers/message.js -> build/resolvers/message.js
src/resolvers/product.js -> build/resolvers/product.js
src/resolvers/stripe.js -> build/resolvers/stripe.js
src/sessionsObserver.js -> build/sessionsObserver.js
```

As you see there are not *.css | *.html files here.

Answer (score 1):

I've found workaround. After build process im picking by bash script all HTML, CSS files and copy them to demanded directories:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# strict mode http://redsymbol.net/articles/unofficial-bash-strict-mode/

echo "Running build script"
rm -rf build

# compile is an alias to classic build
npm run compile

# create directories for HTML and CSS files
mkdir ./build/lib/emailBuilder/templates
mkdir ./build/lib/emailBuilder/styles

# Find and copy HTML templates
for FILE in $(find ./src -name  '*.html'); do
  cp $FILE ./build/lib/emailBuilder/templates
done

# Find and copy styles
for FILE in $(find ./src -name  '*.css'); do
  cp $FILE ./build/lib/emailBuilder/styles
done
```